# How can change my direction when culture change?

Tags: asp.net, css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sf-menu { line-height: 1.0; margin:0px}
    .sf-menu ul { position: absolute; top: -10px; width: 10em;list-style-type: none; }
        .sf-menu ul li { width: 100%; }
    .sf-menu li:hover { visibility: inherit; }
    .sf-menu li { float:; position: relative; }
</style>
```

In float: how can change to left or right when culture change from rtl to ltr ?

Comment: Write two separate stylesheets, one for rtl and the other for ltr, and use javascript to apply the appropriate one.

Comment: @Asad it is easier to just set an attribute or a class by Javascript. The direction attribute should be present anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantically correct way is to set the correct `dir`ection attribute and then test it in CSS.

If you already set the direction in the `html` tag (as [this example on W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#blocklevel-bidi) does), then the CSS would look like:

```
.sf-menu { line-height: 1.0; margin:0px}
.sf-menu ul { position: absolute; top: -10px; width: 10em;list-style-type: none; }
.sf-menu ul li { width: 100%; }
.sf-menu li:hover { visibility: inherit; }
.sf-menu li { float:left; position: relative; }
html[dir="rtl"] .sf-menu li { float: right; } /* <<< here */
```